# What does +a + +b mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

There was an answer to a nested array problem on stack overflow that involved a return statement +a + +b. (no period) What is this? What does it do? It seems to add, but I'm not sure how it does that. How does it differ from a + b? The code is below, and it works:

```
var array= [1, 2, [3, 4], [], [5]];
var sum = array.toString().split(",").reduce(function(a, b) { return +a + +b; 
});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: The `+` in front coerces a variable to a number.

Comment: `"5" + 6 === "56"` whereas `+"5" + 6 === 11`

Comment: The `+` in front of a variable means the developer doesn't know what is going on but tries to calculate anyway, if possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `+` before the variable is the unary `+` operator. You are probably familiar with the unary `-`, e.g. `-x`.

Both `+x` and `-x` convert `x` to a number, but `-x` also changes its sign. This is not the primary purpose of the existance of the unary `+`, but it is a nice sideeffect.

Therefore, the difference between `a + b` and `+a + +b` would be visible from this example:

```
x = '9';          // '9'
x = +'9';         // 9
x = '9' + '9';    // '99'
x = +'9' + +'9';  // 18
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is dynamically typed, but has no built-in operators for casting a value to ensure it is the right type for an operation. Consequently, various tricks are used when it's important that a value is treated as a number, or a string, etc.

In this case, the operator being used is the "unary +" which is the natural counterpart of the "unary -" that would be used to write a negative number: just as "-x" means "0 - x", "+x" means "0 + x". On a number, this has no effect, but other values will be converted to a number.

This is important because the "binary +" operator does different things depending on the type of its operands: if a was a string, a + b would mean "append two strings together" rather than "sum two numbers".

Given an imaginary cast_to_number function, the equation could be more readably written as `return cast_to_number(a) + cast_to_number(b)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a` or `b` were of type String, adding a `+` operator in front of it will coerce it to a number.

This ensures that `’1’ + ‘1’` will be `2` (addition of `number`s) and not `11` (concatenation of `string`s).

Answer (score 0):

javascript has a unary operator `+` and `-`, both of them converts the operand to a number type, but the `-` operator negate the result.

for example:

```
> -'20'
-20
> +'500' + +'600'
1100
```

Answer (score 0):

The `+` unary operator is used for explicit coercion in JavaScript.

Even though some developers look down upon it, saying `var num = 3 + +c;` is rather ugly especially to people not aware of the coercion at hand, potentially even "error-like" looking piece of code.

The most common practical use of the `+` unary operator is probably to get a number timestamp of the date

```
var timestamp = +new Date(); // this works!
```

Perhaps a good piece of memorablia is the `-` unary operator, which for some reason our human brain seems much happier to interpret. Basically, if we see `var x = -c;` we presume the compiler:

1. Attempts to do a value to number coercion of the variable `c`
2. If it can return a number, flip the sign and return the negative number (`-`)

The `+` unary operator does the same thing, only without the sign flipping.

Comment: "...which for some reason our human brain seems much happier to interpret"; I think it's rather simpler than that: the unary - actually has a purpose, the unary + only really exists as its complement, and its side-effect as a casting operator is accidental.

Comment: @IMSoP Yeah, it's kind of funny from neurotical perspective, because the information of a double positive comes of as unnecessary to our cognitive senses and our brain is programmed to ignore it as redundant information.

Comment: I don't think we need to bring psychology in here at all. In a more strongly typed language, the operator would literally do nothing: it would act on a number, and result in that same number; a sane compiler would probably optimise it out of existence. It exists because of some language designer's desire for symmetry, and is then abused for a side effect because JS doesn't have any syntax for casting values.